# Create Animation Sequence file with alpha from Array of Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, alpha, webp

Good day.

How to encode array of bitmaps to Webp animated file or another well-supported animated format?

I try to do  webp encoder and gif encoder but it does not supports alpha channel. Background is still black...

Answer (score 0):

I have to use this code https://github.com/dragon66/android-gif-animated-writer
Nice encoder with alpha layer for android